# Override class value

Tags: javascript, node.js

During unit testing, is it possible to change a class definition with a function?

The below code does not work.

```
describe('Test Serializble',(){

    class Bar{}
    class Foo{}
    function setBarObjectProprietyOfFoo(){
        class Bar extends Serializable {
            id: string
        }

        class Foo extends Serializable {
            bar: Bar
        }
    }
    it('should not pass undefined',()=>{
        setBarObjectProprietyOfFoo()
        const foo = Foo.fromJson(undefined)
        expect(foo).deep.equal(null)
    })
    it('should not pass null',()=>{
        setBarObjectProprietyOfFoo()
        const foo = Foo.fromJson(null)
        expect(foo).deep.equal(null)
    })
})
```

Comment: The expectation of what you have written, would be that the different definition of `Bar` and `Foo` would only exist within the functions that they are defined.  Their scope would not exceed those functions.

Comment: @Taplar so is it is impossible to change the value of Bar and Foo (in the `describe` scope) through a function ?

Comment: However, from a testing standpoint, this personally doesn't make sense what you are trying to do with your example.  You are literally testing logic that only exists in your unit test.  You're not testing real code.

Comment: Scope rules apply to classes the same way that a `var x` within a function is not accessible outside of that function scope.